# Update dataframe values by broadcasting series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Trying to update a portion of a dataframe with values from a series.

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,(5,5)),columns =list('ABCDE'))
print df


    A   B   C   D   E
0  38  13  73  10  76
1   6  80  65  17   2
2  77  72   7  26  51
3  21  19  85  12  29
4  30  15  51  69  88
```

with a series:

```
ser = pd.Series(index =list('CBADE'),data = range(-5,0))

C   -5
B   -4
A   -3
D   -2
E   -1
dtype: int64
```

Lets take a slice for updating

```
criteria = df['A'] < 25

criteria:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
```

trying:

```
df[criteria] = ser
df.loc[criteria,:] = ser
etc.
```

desired output:

```
     A   B   C   D   E
0  38  13  73  10   76
1  -3  -4  -5  -2   -1
2  77  72   7  26   51
3  -3  -4  -5  -2   -1
4  30  15  51  69   88
```

i want to honor the column index and *ignore* the row index, using the boolean criteria and broadcasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `fillna` with a series
You can make your `df` `np.nan` with `mask`
This works

```
df.mask(criteria).fillna(ser)
```

[image]

---

Comment: Very nice solution - i didn't think of using `mask` for this task

Comment: I chose this solution since it was purer pandas solution but willing to reconsider. MaxU what do you think?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
df.loc[criteria, ser.index] = ser[np.newaxis, :]
```

This ensures proper broadcasting (by `np.newaxis`) and that column index is honored (by specifying `ser.index`).

Comment: Yes this is cool - thanks. What i had done was set my values to 0.0  and then availed of the .add() method that broadcasts nicely, though a little crazy as i was needing a simple set option.